# what is the simplest way and what applications to use in making an exe file that runs .swf file assetss

Tags: flash, game-development

I'm developing a game as part of my IT project. It is an offline retro game that resembles a Street Fighter-style arcade fighting game. Since.swf files can be used as assets, I obtained some resources in that format to utilize for now, but I'm not sure how to launch the exe application.

i have searched it up on google and other sites but they all involve flash builder so i'm trying my luck in case you know how simpler methods
i'm only a beginner with no idea where and how to start this pc game so i would appreciate all answers and recommendations

Comment: If you can lay your hands on any Flash authoring suite (CS5, CS5.5, CS6, Animate) you can output a standalone EXE projector. Otherwise, what you have found is correct: use Flash/Flex Builder to produce an AIR application.